# Awkward tag conjugations

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The following tags (specifically their synonym associations are backwards) seem awkward:

- [recommend](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommend) should be "recommendations", e.g. "This question is about recommendations ...", as the (plural) answers will be recommendations
- [book](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) should be "books", usually this will be a plea for recommendations.  Plus "books" agrees with SO.
- [marking](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/markings/synonyms) should be markings

Comment: I can fix this, just give me till after lunch.

Comment: You should probably mark Kortuk's answer as accepted.

Comment: @reem, what to up the stats or something? :P

Comment: No, because it is the answer to your question and to avoid the Community user bumping your question for all of eternity.

Comment: @reem ah.  I think another way to stop that is to upvote an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be all fixed.

There are synonyms in the correct direction now. let me know if there are more you have problems with.